# Ember - Sharing code between two EAK projects

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I hava two emberjs projects both use EAK as the basic project structure. There are some common code i want to share between these two projects: templates, views(and the related stylesheets) some utility classes etc. But there are some doubts i want to figure out:

1. Should i put the common code into a separate eak project?
2. Should i use some package manager(bower maybe) to mange project
   dependency?
3. EAK use its custom resolver to find ember classes under specific
   directories(views,controllers etc), so should i copy the common code
   into these directories or just extend the resolver to write my own
   finding logic?

Any push in the right direction will be a tremendous help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar situation. We scaffolded with Yeoman which means we have bower for dependencies and grunt for building. I'm not sure how this applies to EAK, so take it with a grain of salt.

Our decision was to keep the common code in a separate project. It got a little complicated working through all of the dependencies, and in the end it involved doing some grunt build work to make sure that exactly everything we needed (nothing more or less) got included from the common project when it was added as a dependency to child projects via bower. A dependency manager like Bower is critical because you'll want to be able to pin your child projects (consumers, whatever) to a specific version of the common code while you work on new features therein.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly find to extend the resolved to add directories as fault backs. Here's a sample code:

```
var appPath = "apps/ordering/";
var resolver = Ember.DefaultResolver.extend({
  resolveTemplate: function (parsedName) {
    parsedName.fullNameWithoutType = appPath + parsedName.fullNameWithoutType;
    # fallback to raw templates (used for compatibility with non-Ember/emblem templates)
    return this._super(parsedName) ||
      Ember.TEMPLATES[parsedName.fullNameWithoutType + ".raw"]
  }
});
```

Essentially you could call `this._super` with different paths in the right order to have the faultbacks.

Hope this helps